# Excel VBA Range.Value type mismatch?

Tags: vba, excel

I've written code to delete a row if a cell in column G has the value " - ". However, I'm getting a type mismatch when referring to the cell in the for each loop. I know the problem is coming from "curr.Value," but I don't know how to fix it. Any ideas?

Here's my code:

```
Sub deleteRows()
Dim curr As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Workbooks("ExtractedColumns").Sheets("practice")
For Each curr In
    Workbooks("ExtractedColumns").Sheets("practice").Range("G:G")
     If curr.Value = " - " Then
        EntireRow.Delete
     End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried printing the value of `curr` when it gives you the type mismatch error?

Comment: You need to test for `IsError`.

Comment: you need curr.EntireRow.Delete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to assign the Value to a variant and checking the type.

```
Dim vVal as Variant


.....

vVal = curr.Value
if IsError(vVal) then 

etc
....
```

Comment: sorry, but the reason for the errors are because he in not trapping cells with errors, no need to assign an extra variable. He can just just `If IsError(curr.Value) Then`

Answer (score 2):

First, when you loop:

```
For Each curr In
    Workbooks("ExtractedColumns").Sheets("practice").Range("G:G")
```

the syntax suppose to be in 1 line:

```
For Each curr In Workbooks("ExtractedColumns").Sheets("practice").Range("G:G")
```

(unless you had `-` between the 2 lines of code, or you didn't share your code as you have it).

However, you already assigned `Workbooks("ExtractedColumns").Sheets("practice")` to `ws` in the previous line, so why not use `For Each curr In ws.Range("G:G")`?

Furthermore, looping through your entire column G will take forever, loop through only occupied cells in Column G, with:

```
For Each curr In ws.Range("G1:G" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row)
```

2nd reason, once you find the line where `curr.Value = " - "`, and you want to delete that entire row, you need to use `curr.EntireRow.Delete`.

And last, like mentioned by @Comintern, you need to trap cells with errors, you don't need to assign another variable to the `curr.Value`, just use `If IsError(curr.Value) Then`.

**Code**

```
Sub deleteRows()

Dim curr As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Workbooks("ExtractedColumns").Sheets("practice")

' loop through only occupied cells in Column G
For Each curr In ws.Range("G1:G" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row)
    On Error Resume Next
    If IsError(curr.Value) Then ' check if cell.value return an error
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            Err.Clear
            On Error GoTo 0
        End If
    Else ' current cell.value doesn't return an error
        If curr.Value = " - " Then
            curr.EntireRow.Delete '<-- delete entire row
        End If
    End If
Next curr

End Sub
```

Comment: To say there is no need a add a reference variable is a little pedantic. It was merely something that would explain to him what the error was and for him to do something about the error.

Comment: @PaulG it's not pedantic, it's just not the reason for the error, and now -1 my answer (which has no error) :)

Comment: @ShaiRado Thanks for your answer. I just got around to running it, and I got a runtime error (object variable or with-block variable not set) and it stems from the "for each" line.

Comment: @ShaiRado I just set `curr` as a Variant instead of a Range and changed the range in the `For Each` line to `ws.Range("G:G")`, and the macro ran, but didn't do anything to my spreadsheet at first. After I ran it three times, it worked and deleted the rows with " - " in column G.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the type mismatch error is being caused by curr containing a numeric value, being compared to a string... hard to know for sure without being able to see the rest of the code and how curr is populated but try using `curr.text` which returns a string for your If test, instead of `curr.value`.